# Error 424 vba when trying to assign array(I,1).value into dim string type variable

Tags: excel, vba

This code gives me error 424. May I know how to solve it?

```
Dim a As String
Dim rRange() As Variant
rRange = wb.sheet("sheetname").Range("A1:A5").Value2
```

Now I want to assign a value into a variable

```
a = rRange(I, 1).value
```

Comment: Check for Value of **I**. In the code it is not assigned.

Comment: What is `rRange`?

Comment: @AhmedAU i did assign **I**, the code is in a for loop.

Comment: @BigBen rRange is an array type variant

Comment: An array doesn't have a `.Value`, and perhaps consider a different name. Having `Range` in the name is confusing.

Comment: @BigBen I removed the **.value** and it manages to run without problem.

Comment: That does not make sense. Rule 1: **Always** include `Option Explicit`. Secondly, show [mcve], if your code is in a loop, then showing that loop helps with the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right hand side of the problematic equation is not an Excel Range object, but a 2-dimensional array. Arrays do not have methods and functions (they are not Objects or Classes).

Some comment on your original code:

```
Dim a As String
Dim rRange() As Variant
rRange = wb.sheet("sheetname").Range("A1:A5").Value2 '<- This is where the 2-D variant array is set.

Now i want to assign a value into a variable
For I = <something to something> ' added this for some context
    a = rRange(I, 1).value ' <- ".value" is not applicable to a variant array
next I ' added this for some context
```

What your code could be:

```
Option Explicit
Dim a As String
Dim rRangeValues As Variant '<- () not really required, but in robust code should check for a single value

rRangeValues = wb.sheet("sheetname").Range("A1:A5").Value2 '<- This is where the 2-D variant array is set.

For I = LBound(rRangeValues, 1) to UBound(rRangeValues, 1) 
    a = rRangeValues(I, 1)
    '<Do something with the value>
next I
```

Comment: Thanks bro, that is what I did. I somehow figure it out. Thanks, God Bless<3